# stop page scrolling on tab click

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating some jquery tabs, whenever i clicked on it, it always scrolls to top,

here is my html,

```
<div id="my_div">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#tab_1">Tab-1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tab_2">Tab-2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tab_3">Tab-1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried so far,

```
$('#my_div a').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

It didn't help, what i am doing wrong here.
Please help!

**EDIT**

```
<div id="tab_1" class="tab-content">
    <p>tab 1 goes here..</p>
</div>
<div id="tab_2" class="tab-content">
    <p>tab 2 goes here..</p>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#my_div').createTabs();
});
```

Comment: can you share the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your working code

Comment: It's hard to understand from your question what's exactly going wrong.
Please add more info like whats scroll to top and so on.

Comment: Where are the code of tabs data? It can be happening because you haven't added the tabs data yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what jQuery is doing behind the scenes, but the browser behavior is kicking in, so when you have an href with a # it scrolls to the element on that page with the id that matches the #.

Perhaps try:

```
$('#my_div a').click(function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with wrapping your code within doc ready block:

```
$(function(){ // doc ready starts
   $('#my_div').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
   });
});// doc ready ends
```

use the event delegation syntax.